# Jenkins pipeline script - Thread programming

Tags: multithreading, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create multiple threads in a jenkins pipeline script. So, I took simple example as below. But it not working. Could you please let me know?

In the below example, jobMap contains a key as a string and value as List of Strings. When I just display the list, the values printed properly, but when I used 3 different ways to create threads and thus to display, it is not working.

```
for ( item in jobMap ) 
    {           
        def jobList = jobMap.get(item.key);

        **// The following loop is printing the values**
        for (jobb in jobList) 
        {
                 echo "${jobb}"
        }
```

> **// Thread Implementation1:**

```
        Thread.start 
        {

                for (jobb in jobList) 
                {
                 echo "${jobb}"
                }

        }
```

> **// Thread Implementation2:**

```
        def t = new Thread({ echo 'hello' } as Runnable)
        t.start() ;
        t.join();
```

> **// Thread Implementation3:**

```
        t1 = new Thread( new TestMultiThreadSleep(jobList));
        t1.start();         
    }



    class TestMultiThreadSleep implements Runnable {
   String jobs;
   public TestMultiThreadSleep(List jobs) {
      this.jobs = jobs;
   }



     @Override
       public void run() 
{
       echo "coming here"
         for (jobb in jobs) 
            {
                 echo "${jobb}"
            }                      
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Jenkins has special step - [parallel()](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/parallelism-and-distributed-builds-jenkins). In this step you can build another jobs or call Pipeline code.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to think of Pipeline code as a dialect or subset of Groovy.

The CPS transformer ("continuation-passing style") in the workflow script engine turns the Groovy code into something that can be interpreted in a serialized form, passed between different JVMs, etc.

You can probably imagine that this will not work at all well with threads.

If you need threads, you'll have to work within a `@NonCPS` annotated class or function. This class or function must not call any CPS groovy code - so it can't invoke closures, access the workflow script context, etc.

That's *why* using the `parallel` step is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario you should just use a `parallel` block. Now if you really need to have a worker running in the background for a `Jenkinsfile` (E.g. trying to read a `streaming REST` endpoint), keep reading this answer.

I am not 100% aware of the complications of this approach but I think I found a way to spin up threads and monitor their progress `from a CPS block` (like script block) in a Jenkinsfile.

***1. write a `TestMultiThreadSleep` class*** Modified to be in a non CPS context.

```
class TestMultiThreadSleep implements Runnable {
  private def jobs
  private def processedJobs
  private def finished = false

  public TestMultiThreadSleep(List jobs) {
    this.jobs = jobs;
  }

  @NonCPS
  def getProcessedJobs() {
    processedJobs
  }

  @NonCPS
  def isFinished() {
    finished
  }

  @NonCPS
  void run() {
    for (jobb in jobs) {
      // process what ever you want and 
      // populate the memeber processedJobs with the output.
      // You can not use any Jenkinsfile DSL method.
    }
    finished = true                    
  }
}
```

***2. Submit your runnable to an executionService*** This method will keep your runnable running in a nonCPS context. As far as I know even if you don't explicitly call the `executor.shutDown()` method, the `submit` method will instantiate a `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService` object. This is a delegate that should safely shut down the thread under the hood.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

@NonCPS
void submitWorker(worker) {
  def executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
  executor.submit(worker)
}
```

***3. submit your runnable from a CPS context and write a wait block*** this way of monitoring is really important, I found out that jenkins pipeline timeouts are not applicable for `nonCPS wait periods`, these periods are considered Quite periods for Jenkins and it defaults to 5 mins regardless of the options timeout you have set.

```
...
script {
  def runnable = new TestMultiThreadSleep(jobList)
  submit(runnable)
  
  int elapsedSecs = 0
  int timeout = 40
  while(!runnable.isFinished() && elapsedSecs <= timeout) {
    sleep(1)
    elapsedSecs++
  }
}
...
```